# How can I make a workspace-folder level build script visible in the Eclipse Project Explorer?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a number of interdependent projects in an Eclipse workspace. Eclipse manages dependencies between them within the IDE but I'm starting work on a master build script that will sit in the folder about all the projects (the workspace folder).

I haven't decided on if I will use Maven, Gradle or Ant/Ivy tet, but my question is, is there a way so that I can see a build script in the workspace folder in the Project/Package explorer? Currently it only shows me projects, but assuming I decide on an Ant build, I want to be able to see the main build.xml file in this window.

I've played around with settings to no avail. Is it possible? If not, should I just set up an external run configuration instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting the build files directly in the workspace folder is a very bad idea for many reasons and this is why it seems just impossible to do so.  The workspace is just that.. a project container.

I see two ways to go about your situation :

1 - Create a master project that will serve the same purpose as your workspace.  Then move all your projects as sub folders of this project folder.  You will have the folder structure you want.  To fix the project structure and get back each project in the workspace you can use the import function and import an existing project.  Make sure you do not select copy in the workspace option of the import.  This will allow you to have a project in your workspace folder that does not actually live in the workspace directly.  Newer versions of eclipse will handle correctly nested projects like this, older versions could not. Note this technique also works for projects that are not sub folders of the workspace, they can be anywhere on your hard drive and still show up in your eclipse workspace UI.

2 - Another option is to create a master project but leave everything at the same level (do not place project-components inside the project folder) Then arrange your build script to refer to the other projects via relative paths.  Note that with some build tools this is not even necessary as they will look at their repository.

I have used both layout successfully in builds with Ant and Maven.  Going to try Ivy soon cause Maven is as painful as it is blessfull.  Most likely an Ant-Ivy combination donno yet.

In a personnal note I think the second option is better suited for scalability.  Since all projects are on the same level it makes it easier to reuse a component-project in other master projects without having to make exceptions.  Basically you end up having two types of projects.  The actual code projects that are the building blocks of your application and the assembly projects that create the final finished product.  That way you can get a good separation between the build mechanism for your products and your project.  This is another way that maven irritates me as for many options we must pot them in a master POM that projects inherit from.  Now to build things slightly differently in different projects one has to augment the master POM with specificities of each.  I would much prefer placing this in the master project than having to spread it all over the place.

Anyways, my 2 cent, I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to view the file in your Package explorer / Navigator view unless it is part of a project.

Some alternative options:

1. Create a General project in Eclipse and instead of using default location explicitly specify one. Before browsing location change the 'Choose file system' from default to RSE
2. Create your own Eclipse plugin with File explorer view

If you are using Ant you can create a launch configuration under external tools like you said. Maven has a different project structure to Eclipse, although you can override this. There is a [Maven plugin](http://maven.apache.org/eclipse-plugin.html) to use with Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

I have never heard of a way to create files on the Eclipse Workspace level.

Our Ant solution is an extra (not Java-) Project in the Workspace with a `build.xml` for all other (Java-) Projects. 
To be able to reach `build.xml` files in other Projects you can edit the launch configuration (use right click --> *Run As* --> *Ant Build...*). Go to the *Main* tab and choose the Workspace-root-directory as the *Base Directory* (with the Button *Browse File System...*).

As an **external** build (and test, code check, source code repository, ...) solution I would recommend the combination of

- Eclipse (with subclipse)
- Subversion
- Ant
- Hudson (plus some plugins)